# Kafka new partition

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to add another consumer to my topic to increase the speed. I have seen the documentation [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) and can use

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server broker_host:port --alter --topic my_topic_name --partitions 2`

but can I do it directly while the messages arrive?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. However, this could be interesting: [How Kafka guarantee the messages order while we increase the partitions in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64096005/how-kafka-guarantee-the-messages-order-while-we-increase-the-partitions-in-runti/64096753#64096753)

Comment: There are other ways to increase speed for single partitions like polling rate, by the way